# (De)serialize RFC-3339 timestamp with serde to time-rs OffsetDateTime

Tags: rust, serde, rfc3339

My goal is to (de)serialize objects with [RFC-3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) timestamps from Json to Rust structs (and vice versa) using [serde](https://serde.rs/) and [time-rs](https://github.com/time-rs/time).

I would expect this ...

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use time::{OffsetDateTime};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct DtoTest {
    pub timestamp: OffsetDateTime,
}

fn main() {
    let deserialization_result = serde_json::from_str::<DtoTest>("{\"timestamp\": \"2022-07-08T09:10:11Z\"}");
    let dto = deserialization_result.expect("This should not panic");
    println!("{}", dto.timestamp);
}
```

... to create the struct and display the timestamp as the output, but I get ...

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'This should not panic: Error("invalid type: string \"2022-07-08T09:10:11Z\", expected an `OffsetDateTime`", line: 1, column: 36)', src/main.rs:12:38
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

My dependencies look like this:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.138", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.82"
time = { version = "0.3.11", features = ["serde"] }
```

According to the [documentation of the time-rs crate](https://time-rs.github.io/internal-api/time/serde/index.html), this seems to be possible but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default serialization format for `time` is some internal format. If you want other formats, you should enable the `serde-well-known` feature and use the [`serde`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/serde/index.html) module to choose the format you want:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct DtoTest {
    #[serde(with = "time::serde::rfc3339")]
    pub timestamp: OffsetDateTime,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution below is based on the [serde_with](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/guide/serde_as/#switching-from-serdes-with-to-serde_as) crate. As per its [documentation](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/guide/serde_as/#serde_as-annotation), it aims to be more flexible and composable.

```
use serde_with::serde_as;
use time::OffsetDateTime;
use time::format_description::well_known::Rfc3339;

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct DtoTest {
    #[serde_as(as = "Rfc3339")]
    pub timestamp: OffsetDateTime,
}
```

And the `Cargo.toml` file should have:

```
[dependencies]
serde_with = { version = "2", features = ["time_0_3"] }
```

At the following [page](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/guide/serde_as_transformations/index.html#deserialize-transformations-available) are listed all De/Serialize transformations available.

Comment: This doesn't work. `serde_as` requires code specifically for it.